# Fastest Sobel Edge Detection C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, edge-detection

I want to make a program that implements sobel edge detection.
This is my code :

```
private Bitmap SobelEdgeDetect(Bitmap ori)
{
        Bitmap b = original;
        Bitmap bb = original;
        int width = b.Width;
        int height = b.Height;
        int[,] gx = new int[,] { { -1, 0, 1 }, { -2, 0, 2 }, { -1, 0, 1 } };
        int[,] gy = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { -1, -2, -1 } };

        int[,] allPixR = new int[width, height];
        int[,] allPixG = new int[width, height];
        int[,] allPixB = new int[width, height];

        int limit = 128 * 128;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                allPixR[i, j] = b.GetPixel(i, j).R;
                allPixG[i, j] = b.GetPixel(i, j).G;
                allPixB[i, j] = b.GetPixel(i, j).B;
            }
        }

        int new_rx = 0, new_ry = 0;
        int new_gx = 0, new_gy = 0;
        int new_bx = 0, new_by = 0;
        int rc, gc, bc;
        for (int i = 1; i < b.Width - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < b.Height - 1; j++)
            {

                new_rx = 0;
                new_ry = 0;
                new_gx = 0;
                new_gy = 0;
                new_bx = 0;
                new_by = 0;
                rc = 0;
                gc = 0;
                bc = 0;

                for (int wi = -1; wi < 2; wi++)
                {
                    for (int hw = -1; hw < 2; hw++)
                    {
                        rc = allPixR[i + hw, j + wi];
                        new_rx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * rc;
                        new_ry += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * rc;

                        gc = allPixG[i + hw, j + wi];
                        new_gx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * gc;
                        new_gy += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * gc;

                        bc = allPixB[i + hw, j + wi];
                        new_bx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * bc;
                        new_by += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * bc;
                    }
                }
                if (new_rx * new_rx + new_ry * new_ry > limit || new_gx * new_gx + new_gy * new_gy > limit || new_bx * new_bx + new_by * new_by > limit)
                    bb.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black);

                //bb.SetPixel (i, j, Color.FromArgb(allPixR[i,j],allPixG[i,j],allPixB[i,j]));
                else
                    bb.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
        return bb;

  }
```

i want to using lockbits so my program can run faster, but i actually still not understand how to use it.
could anyone give some explanation or example code?

Comment: Your original code had the Sobel algorithm but was slow because of `GetPixel` and `SetPixel`. Now your code should use `LockBits` on *both* bitmaps (input and output) and access the pixels by `(x,y)` as I demonstrated in my answer. You're very close now - don't give up.

Comment: could you tell me, which one of the part of my code should exchange to lockbits?
i feel very depression.
thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really need to use [`LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) instead of `GetPixel` and `SetPixel`.

So you create a `BitmapData` object that contains all of the pixel data:

```
// lock the input bitmap's bits  
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
    original.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height), 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.Read, original.PixelFormat);
```

Then, you can get the address of the first scan line (i.e. the first row of pixels):

```
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
```

Now you have two choices. If you're happy to mark your function as `unsafe` then you can access the pixels directly using pointer arithmetic, like this

```
byte* pPixels = (byte*)ptr.ToPointer();
```

which gives you a pointer to the first byte of an RGB pixel (assuming 24bpp). Then you can access an individual pixel at `(x,y)` using pointer arithmetic. First you determine how many bytes per pixel (if you don't already know)

```
int nBytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(original.PixelFormat) / 8;
```

Then calculate the index to the pixel you want

```
byte* pPixelAtXY = pPixels + (y * bmpData.Stride) + (x * nBytesPerPixel);
```

This gives you `unsafe` access to the pixels in a `Bitmap` which you can do for the input and output bitmaps for fastest speed. Note that to use unsafe code, you need to [mark your function as unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [edit your project properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you don't want to use `unsafe` code, you can still speed things up by copying all of the pixel data to a `byte` array before processing and then copy it back afterwards. As the MSDN example showed

```
// Get the address of the first line.
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

// Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

// Copy the RGB values into the array.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

// Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.   
for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
    rgbValues[counter] = 255;

// Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
```

Whichever method you use, when you have finished with the pixel data, you *must* release it using `UnlockBits`

```
original.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Comment: could you give a complete source code, i've try it but i get any errors.

Comment: @user1442032 If you edit your question to show your new code, then we can see what's wrong.