# Edge Detection with Lockbits C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, edge-detection, lockbits

I made a program that implements an edge detection algorithm,
but it takes a long time to process.
I've read about using lockbits, and unsafe state instead of getpixel and setpixel, but I still don't understand how to use it.

This is my example code:

```
private Bitmap SobelEdgeDetect(Bitmap original)
        {
            Bitmap b = original;
            Bitmap bb = original;
            int width = b.Width;
            int height = b.Height;
            int[,] gx = new int[,] { { -1, 0, 1 }, { -2, 0, 2 }, { -1, 0, 1 } };
            int[,] gy = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { -1, -2, -1 } };

            int[,] allPixR = new int[width, height];
            int[,] allPixG = new int[width, height];
            int[,] allPixB = new int[width, height];

            int limit = 128 * 128;

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    allPixR[i, j] = b.GetPixel(i, j).R;
                    allPixG[i, j] = b.GetPixel(i, j).G;
                    allPixB[i, j] = b.GetPixel(i, j).B;
                }
            }

            int new_rx = 0, new_ry = 0;
            int new_gx = 0, new_gy = 0;
            int new_bx = 0, new_by = 0;
            int rc, gc, bc;
            for (int i = 1; i < b.Width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < b.Height - 1; j++)
                {

                    new_rx = 0;
                    new_ry = 0;
                    new_gx = 0;
                    new_gy = 0;
                    new_bx = 0;
                    new_by = 0;
                    rc = 0;
                    gc = 0;
                    bc = 0;

                    for (int wi = -1; wi < 2; wi++)
                    {
                        for (int hw = -1; hw < 2; hw++)
                        {
                            rc = allPixR[i + hw, j + wi];
                            new_rx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * rc;
                            new_ry += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * rc;

                            gc = allPixG[i + hw, j + wi];
                            new_gx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * gc;
                            new_gy += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * gc;

                            bc = allPixB[i + hw, j + wi];
                            new_bx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * bc;
                            new_by += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * bc;
                        }
                    }
                    if (new_rx * new_rx + new_ry * new_ry > limit || new_gx * new_gx + new_gy * new_gy > limit || new_bx * new_bx + new_by * new_by > limit)
                        bb.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black);


                    else
                        bb.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Transparent);
                }
            }
            return bb;
        }
```

I am using the fastbitmap class, which I implement like this:

```
private Bitmap SobelEdgeDetectTwo(Bitmap original)
        {
            int width = original.Width;
            int height = original.Height;
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width,height);
            FastBitmap b = new FastBitmap(original);
            FastBitmap bb = new FastBitmap(result);

            b.LockBitmap();
            bb.LockBitmap();

            int[,] gx = new int[,] { { -1, 0, 1 }, { -2, 0, 2 }, { -1, 0, 1 } };
            int[,] gy = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { -1, -2, -1 } };

            int[,] allPixR = new int[width, height];
            int[,] allPixG = new int[width, height];
            int[,] allPixB = new int[width, height];

            int limit = 128 * 128;

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    var pixel = b.GetPixel(i,j);
                    allPixR[i, j] = pixel.Red;
                    allPixG[i, j] = pixel.Green;
                    allPixB[i, j] = pixel.Blue;

                }
            }

            int new_rx = 0, new_ry = 0;
            int new_gx = 0, new_gy = 0;
            int new_bx = 0, new_by = 0;
            int rc, gc, bc;
            for (int i = 1; i < width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < height - 1; j++)
                {

                    new_rx = 0;
                    new_ry = 0;
                    new_gx = 0;
                    new_gy = 0;
                    new_bx = 0;
                    new_by = 0;
                    rc = 0;
                    gc = 0;
                    bc = 0;

                    for (int wi = -1; wi < 2; wi++)
                    {
                        for (int hw = -1; hw < 2; hw++)
                        {
                            rc = allPixR[i + hw, j + wi];
                            new_rx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * rc;
                            new_ry += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * rc;

                            gc = allPixG[i + hw, j + wi];
                            new_gx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * gc;
                            new_gy += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * gc;

                            bc = allPixB[i + hw, j + wi];
                            new_bx += gx[wi + 1, hw + 1] * bc;
                            new_by += gy[wi + 1, hw + 1] * bc;
                        }
                    }

                    if (new_rx * new_rx + new_ry * new_ry > limit || new_gx * new_gx + new_gy * new_gy > limit || new_bx * new_bx + new_by * new_by > limit)
                    {
                        PixelData p = new PixelData(Color.Black);
                        bb.SetPixel(i, j, p);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PixelData p = new PixelData(Color.Transparent);
                        bb.SetPixel(i, j, p);

                    }

                }
            }


            b.UnlockBitmap();
            bb.UnlockBitmap();

            return result;
        }
```

However, the image doesn't change at all.
Could you give me advice about which part of my code is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easiest to use a class like [FastBitmap](http://code.google.com/p/renderterrain/source/browse/trunk/FastBitmap.cs?r=14). Just add a FastBitmap and use GetPixel() on that class instead of on your Bitmap, the rest can be the same.

Something like this:

```
Bitmap dstBmp = new Bitmap(width, height, original.PixelFormat);
FastBitmap fastBitmap = new FastBitmap(dstBmp);
fastBitmap.LockBitmap();
//...
var pixel = fastBitmap.GetPixel(x,y);
//...
fastBitmap.UnlockBitmap();
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for FastBitmap. Always used LockBits manually after discovered the terrible slow down of Bitmap.GetPixel

Comment: I made a program that draws fractals a while ago and discovered that yes, Set and GetPixel are incredibly slow. But it's easy to get around it with a class like FastBitmap, and it hides the pointer logic :)

Comment: i've solved my problem about the error. i can implement the FastBitmap class to my function above, but the image doesn't change at all.

Comment: How can i set the transparent color?

Comment: i tested it stopwatch . before 600 ms to 1100 ms  . now its 60 to 100ms.
**this fastbitmap.cs 10xFASTER than normal bitmap**.
 the code run before i press F5 !!  thank you.
.you may want to change  Red , Green Blue to R , G B in the Fastbitmap.cs  if you dont wanna change  your code

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's see what we can do - a quick Google found [this](http://www.copypastecode.com/68220/), which can be simply adapted to your function something like this

```
private Bitmap SobelEdgeDetect(Bitmap original)
{
    int width = original.Width;
    int height = original.Height;

    int BitsPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(original.PixelFormat);
    int OneColorBits = BitsPerPixel / 8;

    BitmapData bmpData = original.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, original.PixelFormat);
    int position;
    int[,] gx = new int[,] { { -1, 0, 1 }, { -2, 0, 2 }, { -1, 0, 1 } };
    int[,] gy = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { -1, -2, -1 } };
    byte Threshold = 128;

    Bitmap dstBmp = new Bitmap(width, height, original.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData dstData = dstBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, dstBmp.PixelFormat);

    unsafe
    {
        byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* dst = (byte*)dstData.Scan0.ToPointer();

        for (int i = 1; i < height - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
            {
                int NewX = 0, NewY = 0;

                for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
                {
                    for (int jj = 0; jj < 3; jj++)
                    {
                        int I = i + ii - 1;
                        int J = j + jj - 1;
                        byte Current = *(ptr + (I * width + J) * OneColorBits);
                        NewX += gx[ii, jj] * Current;
                        NewY += gy[ii, jj] * Current;
                    }
                }
                position = ((i * width + j) * OneColorBits);
                if (NewX * NewX + NewY * NewY > Threshold * Threshold)
                    dst[position] = dst[position + 1] = dst[position + 2] = 255;
                else
                    dst[position] = dst[position + 1] = dst[position + 2] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    original.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    dstBmp.UnlockBits(dstData);

    return dstBmp;
}
```

It's not complete copy/paste solution but you should be able to see how the original author is accessing the pixel data by using `LockBits` in exactly the way you need. The rest is up to you ;-)

You will need to set the `unsafe` option in your project properties as I explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632698/2065121) to your previous question.

Comment: finally, i can implement it.
but, i always get the 'white' color instead of 'transparent'.
can you help me how to fix this?
i want to use Color.Transparent in the image result